# Sorting singly linked list with bubble sort

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, linked-list, bubble-sort

I've written the following code for sorting a singly linked list using bubble sort. Sorting procedure should sort the nodes of the list on the basis of the data they contain. Sorting the nodes only exchanging the data among them won't be accepted. My code triggers a segmentation fault (core dumped). I think I'm not tracking the head pointer correctly. I'm sharing the full code for the reproduction of results.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;   

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node* create_node(node *head, int data)
{
    node *baby = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    baby->data = data;
    baby->next = NULL;
    
    if(head==NULL)
        head = baby;
    else
    {
        node *curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL)
            curr = curr->next;
        curr->next = baby;  
    }
    return head;    
}

void sort_bubble(node *head)
{
    int count=0, i, j, temp;
    bool swapped;
    node *curr, *tempo, *p1, *p2;
    for(curr=head; curr!=NULL; curr=curr->next)
        count = count+1;
    
    for(i=0; i<=(count-2); i++)
    {
        curr = head;
        swapped = false;
        for(j=0; j<=(count-2-i); j++)
        {
            p1 = curr;
            p2 = p1->next;
            if(p1->data > p2->data)
            {
                tempo = p2->next;
                p2->next = p1;
                p1->next = tempo;
                curr = p2;
                swapped = true;
            }
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        if(swapped = false)
            break;
    }
}

void print_list(node *head)
{
    node *curr = head;
    while(curr)
    {
        cout<<curr->data<<" ";
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    int count = 6;
    node *head = NULL;
    
    head = create_node(head, 40);
    head = create_node(head, 10);
    head = create_node(head, 60);
    head = create_node(head, 50);
    head = create_node(head, 20);
    head = create_node(head, 30);
    print_list(head);
    
    sort_bubble(head);
    print_list(head);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the tag for the language you are using

Comment: What use do you think `curr = p2` is?

Comment: "My code triggers a segmentation fault (core dumped)." - Luckily for you, that's one of the easiest issues to catch and debug in your [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). Either loading the core dump into the debugger or just running the program in the debugger should allow you to easily see the stack trace that lead to the fault and inspect relevant variables in the stack frame where it occurs, so you can deduce the cause of it. Btw; why not just use `std::sort`?

Comment: *"I'm sharing the full code for the reproduction of results."* -- Did you try to reduce the amount of code needed to reproduce the crash? For example, are you willing to claim that omitting `head = create_node(head, 30);` removes the crash?  Did you identify which line crashes? (You should.) If it's crashing in `sort_bubble` then there's no need to call `print_list()` afterwards (in the code for this question) since execution never gets there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so far I can see this

```
if(swapped = false)
```

which makes the condition always false, and therefore the loop will never break. That makes the function run infinitely consuming CPU cycles which is probably what it throws the segmentation fault.

Comment: No that's not the spoiler. Even after rectifying that the error persists.